# math.random() and comparison operator clarification

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I know Math.random() generates random numbers, my question is:

1.What is going on by comparing it to .5 (or 50%)?

2.How does that trigger the if statement into working?

3.Is Math.random() getting its numbers from the variable1?

```
 variable1 = 8;
 while (variable1 > 0){
    If(Math.random() < .5){
    variable1--;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 variable1 = 8;
 while (variable1 > 0){
    If(Math.random() < .5){
    variable1--;
    }
 }
```

1. What is going on by comparing it to .5 (or 50%)?

> It's like flipping a coin. `Math.random` returns a number between 0
> and 1. It's 'heads' if less than .5, 'tails' if it's over. `variable1`
> which starts at 8, gets subtracted by 1 every time (and only if) the
> coin flipped is 'heads'

2. How does that trigger the if statement into working?

> Until `variable1` subtracts down to less than 0, this loop will repeat
> and process the `if` condition

3. Is Math.random() getting its numbers from `variable1`?

> No, Math.random() is just generating a new number each time the if
> statement gets processed. `variable1` is only changed when `Math.random()` is less
> than .5

Random, being what it is, could mean this `while` loop repeats infinitely. It's unlikely, but there's no law that says you ever have to eventually get tails on the flip.